# ACCESS Database from PHP

Tags: php, ms-access

I'm having issues connecting my code to the Access database. I know that Access is running 64-bits and I have a 32-bit driver. How can I connect the code to the Access database? I have searched for the answered and nothing seems to work.

This is my code:

```
$dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "C:\wamp\www\New User Form Database1.mdb";

if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
echo (8 * PHP_INT_SIZE) . "-bit";
die("Could not find database file.");
}

$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
```

Comment: Two counter-questions: what is the output of $dbName? You are concatenating your document root and the full path to your MDB file, which does not seem correct to me. Additionally: have you tried defining a DSN and using [odbc_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php)?

Comment: Whether or not you get this working, please be aware that the Access DB engine is not designed for this kind of thing with concurrent multi-user access. I've seen Access databases get really badly mangled in systems like this. You should strongly consider upgrading the DB to something a bit more powerful. SQL Server Express is the logical upgrade path. It should be possible to convert the DB to use the more robust back-end DB engine, but keep your Access front-end the same if you need to.

Comment: Im new to PHP so i dont know what you mean....

Comment: So you believe access isnt a good option for a DB its only storing new users in a business. It would be maximum 5-10 entries a year.